# How to correctly replace na with 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, na, fillna

I have a dataframe and when I run this code:

```
print('NA: ', df.columns[df.isin([np.nan]).any()])
```

it brings:

```
NA:  Index(['col1', 'col2'],
      dtype='object')
```

here how col1 looks for example `df['col1']`:

```
col1
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
...
1.0
1.0
```

However after I do this:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

it turns col1 and col2 into:

```
col1
None
None
None
None
None
...
None
None
```

How to replace Na in those columns correctly? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using inplace and column mapping. You need to pick one between

```py
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].fillna(0, inplace=False)
```

and

```py
df[['col1', 'col2']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

The later return `None`, so your code does

- inplace imputing of 0 where NaNs are
- copy `None` for all entries of `col1` and `col2`

hence your observation.